# nginx "410 gone"

Tags: nginx

I have this configuration and Nginx only returns 410 gone, any idea on how can I fix this?

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name static.srk.pre.is;

    set $rootfolder /home/sites/srk.pre.is/static;

    access_log /home/sites/srk.pre.is/logs/static.access.log;
    error_log /home/sites/srk.pre.is/logs/static.error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    gzip_buffers 16 8k;

    gzip_disable “MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)”;

    location /favicon.ico
    {
        alias $rootfolder/images/favicon.ico;
        expires max;
    }

    location /
    {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        root $rootfolder;
    }
}
```

I've checked the logs but there's nothing in it.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're omitting some conf info.  I very much so doubt that nginx would return `410 Gone` all by itself, without any explicit configuration instruction anywhere to do so.

Answer (score 0):

That was a really stupid mistake.

static.srk.pre.is is a parallels machine but it wasn't mapped correctly inside the /etc/hosts file...

I just had to add the line and the problem did solve correctly.